# In image dataset loading into numpy array, How can I convert image's 3d format into 2d?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning

To load my image dataset, I have done following coding

```
X=[]
for i in range(1,682):
    image=Image.open(str(i)+'.jpg')
    image=image.resize((100,100))
    temp=asarray(image)
    X.append(temp)
```

Shape of X is (681,100,100,3) but I want shape of X to be (681,100,100). How can I do that?

Comment: The size 3 dimension identifies the color of each pixel.  Without it you can only show a b/w image.

Comment: You can use: `image = Image.open(str(i)+'.jpg').convert('LA')` (read image and convert to Grayscale), but as hpaulj commented, image is going to be in Grayscale format.

Comment: now X shape is (681,100,100,2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use opencv to read images it reads images as numpy arrays

```py
import cv2
X=[]
for i in range(1,682):
    temp = cv2.imread(str(i)+'.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    temp = cv2.resize(temp, (100,100))
    X.append(temp)
```